# Run a Curl comand from a jenkins job

Tags: shell, curl, groovy, jenkins, command

can anyone tell me how we can run a curl command from jenkins.
I'm on windows 7 and i'm trying to put .sh on artifactory from a job jenkins.
thanks

Comment: Why is the question tagged Groovy?  Are you looking to use Groovy to accomplish this?  Do have the Groovy plugin?

Comment: yes i have it because i tought it was possible with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand that you want to upload a file to Artifactory by using curl and Artifactory's REST API?

The easiest would be to use the Artifactory plugin, and upload files from your workspace into an Artifactory repository.

If you want to do it without that:

1. Install cURL for Windows on the node
2. Add a "Windows batch script" build step, and call cURL with the right URL

Comment: i did it with artifoctory plugin using generic artifactory but it adds .md5 and .sha1 i don't want to have that , i want just the file . and to read from artifactory and put a file on workspace  i think i need artifactory Pro is it true?